# laravel show method not found exception when shortern URL link is passed in POST request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel working directory on local. All forms are posting data on Local but only `addshow` form is not working on live. I came across that when I filled the link field with a google shortern URL. Laravel gives a method not allowed exception on submission of the form. Putting any other link beside shorten link works fine on live.

```
<form class="" role="form" method="post" action="{{ url('/addshow') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title<span>*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="name" value="" placeholder="Enter Title"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Place<span>*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="place" id="place" value="" placeholder="Enter place"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time<span>Start / End</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" value="<?= date('h:m'); ?>" placeholder="Enter Start time"/>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-lg">
              <input class="form-control" type="time" name="end_time" id="end_time" value="<?php// date('h:m'); ?>" placeholder="Enter End time"/>
            </div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date<span>*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" id="date" value="<?= date('y-m-20y') ?>" placeholder="Enter date"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Link<span>*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="url" name="link" id="link" value="" placeholder="Enter Url"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status<span>*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <select class="form-control" name="status">
                <option value="1">Activated</option>
                <option value="0">Deactivated</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
      <br/>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
      <div class="box-footer clearfix">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
       <span class="pull-right">&nbsp;
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Create" placeholder=""/>
          </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

plus this is route `Route::post('/addshow', 'DashboardController@addshow');`

```
public function addshow(Request $request) {
    echo"<pre>";print_r($request->all());echo"</pre>";exit();
    Shows::create($request->all());
    return redirect(url('/allshows'));
}
```

for the time being validation and other stuff not including to keep it simple

Comment: How about including the code that's causing the issue, what you've done so far to debug it and use proper punctuation and capitalisation!

Comment: debug the request  echo"<pre>";print_r($request->all());echo"</pre>";exit(); but always return empty

Comment: @styphon i explained more can you tell me where i go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens with me too the only solution i came accross that when i put the shortern URL it will give you method not found exception in most cases so simply allow user to enter only last 6 digits or alphabets of URL and save to database . only this way i solved this problem and hope you will find it helpfull . plus you should also see the collation from default to utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

The most critical piece of information that I can gather from your question is that you're getting a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` which tells us that the specific issue is that the request is coming in using a different HTTP method than you have set the route up to handle.

From the code samples you have provided both your form and your route seem to use the `POST` method so it seems that submitting the form is not the cause of the issue. To be certain you could try adding a something like `dd('test');` right at the start of your `addshow` method. If you still get the exception then it means either your form is not actually using the `POST` method or the route is incorrectly configured.

One alternative is that the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is not for `/addshow`. You mention that it appears when you add a Google shortened URL to the link field, does it appear when you enter other links? If so it could be that the Google shortened URL is failing validation and redirecting to a URL that does not use the `GET` method. It's impossible to say for certain without your validation code but it would be worth checking what URL your browser displays when you get the error screen.

Comment: thanks for answering the question @james really appreciate your effort . but i tried to enter links other then shorten URL they all work file and post method work as he suppose to do when there is shorten URL then whole form messed up and there is no post shorten .. i changes post to any and after posting the shorten URL the post array return empty .

Comment: It sounds like something is redirecting you from `POST /addshow` to `GET /addshow` when you use a shortened URL. There's nothing in the code you've uploaded to suggest what is doing this so I suspect it's something in the validation. Can you add the validation code to your answer?

Comment: for the time being i removed all validation . @james just to make it as simpler as possible

Comment: Ah ok, could you try taking a screenshot of your browser when you get the error message and adding it to the question? There might be something in the stack trace that will give us a clue about what's happening.